# How to render a PHP string variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I solve this? It showing:

> [object HTMLCollection].

Code:

```
<?php $a = "A"; ?>
<script>
document.write(<?php echo $a; ?>);
</script>
```

Comment: Xss attack here

Comment: You will get a reference error stating `A is undefined`

Comment: I feel sad when a stack overflow question doesn't contain an actual question

Comment: Pro-tip: you were downvoted here for a waffly title that contained nearly no detail at all. See my edits for the kind of succinctness that is strongly preferred on all internet help sites.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a PHP code is executed, it executes first and then the javascript so you need to escape the quotes :

```
<?php $a = "A"; ?>
<script>
  document.write("<?php echo $a; ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both:

document.write(`'<?php echo $a; ?>'`);  OR

document.write(`"<?php echo $a; ?>"`);